# How to toggle elements in a matrix with range[0,1]?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this matrix,

```
0 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 0
```

And I want to toggle each 1-valued elements to 0 and vice versa:

```
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1
```

If I use the [bitwise complement operator](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions) i.e. `dst = ~src` I got this result

```
255 254 255
254 255 254
255 254 255
```

Of cource I can get the result I want with some arithmetic and looping. But is there any easy way to achieve the matrix I want in OpenCV? Thanks.

**Update:**

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat a = (cv::Mat_<uchar>(3,3) << 0, 1, 0,
                                         1, 0, 1, 
                                         0, 1, 0 );
    cv::Mat b = ~a;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shmiddty: Your suggestion is possible but I don't want to change the matrix type. The matrix is CV_8U and came for "normal" images. It is normalized to [0,1] for some image analysis and in the end it will be normalized again to [0,255].

Comment: Have you tried using the '!' operator instead? The '~' operator is just inverting the bits.

Comment: You should also show your actual matrix declaration. I have no experience with [tag:opencv] but I think your question is at least about plain C++ behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only `ones` and `zeros`, you can do this:

`cv::Mat b = 1 - a;`

Answer (score 3):

One more option is

```
dst = 1 - src;
```

though this will fail if you ever end up with anything not in [1, 0] in your array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dst = src ? 0 : 1;
```

This would implicitly convert the `src` value to `bool`.
Note that any other `src` value than `1` will also be set to `0` using that statement.

Comment: @bsdnoobz I rewrote it omitting the cast (that was a stupid idea anyway, I did it for emphasis in the 1st version).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution

```
dst = !src
```

It saves you some letters to type

Comment: `!` operator is not defined for `cv::Mat`.

Comment: Define it, or apply for each element. There is no way to do it directly with OpenCV